# Stop rotation of image after 360' degree

Tags: android, rotational-matrices

I am trying to rotate image single round from it's center point but I am not able to stop at desire position as I can do rotation but I want to stop rotation after `360'(1 round)`.

```
public class RotateRoundActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{

    private ImageView dialer;
    //private float y=0;
    private float x=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.big_button);
        dialer.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //  double r=Math.atan2(event.getX()-dialer.getWidth()/2, dialer.getHeight()/2-event.getY());

        double r=Math.atan2(event.getX()-dialer.getWidth()/2, dialer.getHeight()/2-event.getY());
        int rotation=(int)Math.toDegrees(r);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x=event.getX();
              //  y=event.getY();
                updateRotation(rotation);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }//switch       

        return true;
    }
```

*Rotation method@*

```
    private void updateRotation(double rot){
        float newRot=new Float(rot);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(newRot,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
        Log.i("demo===>", "matrix==>" + matrix);
     //   Log.i("demo===", "y===>" + y);
        Log.i("demo===", "x===>" + x);

        if(x>250){
            Bitmap reDrawnBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
            dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
        }
        else{
            Bitmap reDrawnBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
            dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Your suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: In which direction you want to rotate? I mean clockwise/ anti-clockwise?

Comment: In both the direction clock and anticlockwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to save previous `rot` value. And add check in `updateRotation` method if `previousRot` is at the left of 360' degrees and `rot` is at the right of 360' degrees then we made 1 round and need stop rotating.

Sample code for clockwise case

```
if (previousRot >= 300 && previousRot <= 360 && rot >= 0 && rot <= 60) {
    rot = 359.99; // or here can be 360'
}
```

For counter clockwise case it is almost the same, but the values swapped

```
if (previousRot >= 0 && previousRot <= 60 && rot >= 300 && rot <= 360) {
    rot = 0;
}
```

This code will stop rotation. From the beginning `previousRot` should be 0 for clockwise case and 359.99 for counter clockwise

---

Another approach is to add one more variable to store total traveled angle. From the beginning `traveledAngle` have to be equal to 0. And if you're rotating in clockwise direction you have to increase it by the difference between `rot` and `previousRot`. When rotating counter clockwise decrease it by the same value.

```
traveledAngle += rot - previousRot;
```

When `traveledAngle` becomes greater than 360' you need to stop rotating in clockwise direction, and when it becomes less than 0, you need to stop rotating in counter clockwise direction.

Comment: How can I get the angle more than 360' degree? It will be increase from 1' to 360'. after 360' it takes 1' degree.

Comment: That's right! For clockwise direction `previousRot` should be 350-360', and `rot` should be about 0-10'. But this numbers are given only for example, it may be 300-360' and 0-60'. The main idea is using `previousRot` value

Comment: Okay. but how can I stop rotation using previousRot? if I am at 1' after one rotation and my previousRot value is 360' then? And what should be logic for anticlockwise?

Comment: Added one more approach to solve the problem using `traveledAngle`

Comment: I like your concept and logic for traveledAngle and rot angle. I have been trying to solve the issue to stop rotation for two days after your comment. And I almost get solution for this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I hadn't get the exact solution but yes almost I was very close to that. so I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have used your demo and added some logic, the newer demo is as below:

```
public class RotateRoundActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    float rot1=0.0F, rot2=0.0F;
    boolean clockwise, rotationDone = false, halfrotated = false;
    int rotcall=0;

    private ImageView dialer;
    //private float y=0;
    private int x=0;
    //private int y=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.big_button);
        dialer.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //  double r=Math.atan2(event.getX()-dialer.getWidth()/2, dialer.getHeight()/2-event.getY());
        double r=Math.atan2(event.getX()-dialer.getWidth()/2, dialer.getHeight()/2-event.getY());
        int rotation=(int)Math.toDegrees(r);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x=(int) event.getX();
                //y=(int) event.getY();
                updateRotation(rotation);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }//switch       

        return true;
    }

    private void updateRotation(double rot){
        float newRot = new Float(rot);

        rotcall++;
        if(rotcall == 1)
            rot1 = new Float(rot);
        if(rotcall == 2)
            rot2 = new Float(rot);
        if(rot1 != 0.0F && rot2 != 0.0F)
            if(rot1 < rot2)
                clockwise = true;
            else
                clockwise = false;
        System.out.println("Rotate :: "+newRot);

        if(clockwise && rot1>=0 ) {
            if(newRot < 0)
                halfrotated = true;
            if(halfrotated && newRot > 0)
                rotationDone = true;
            if(rotationDone)
                newRot = 0;
        }
        if(clockwise && rot1<0) {
            if(newRot > 0)
                halfrotated = true;
            if(halfrotated && newRot < 0)
                rotationDone = true;
            if(rotationDone)
                newRot = 0;
        }
        if(!clockwise && rot1<0) {
            if(newRot > 0)
                halfrotated = true;
            if(halfrotated && newRot < 0)
                rotationDone = true;
            if(rotationDone)
                newRot = 0;
        }
        if(!clockwise && rot1>=0) {
            if(newRot < 0)
                halfrotated = true;
            if(halfrotated && newRot > 0)
                rotationDone = true;
            if(rotationDone)
                newRot = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("Rotation Done :: "+rotationDone);

        if(!rotationDone) {
            //BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) dialer.getDrawable();
            //Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.  YOUR_DRBL  );
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(newRot, width, height);
            System.out.println("x===>" + x);
            //System.out.println("y===>" + y);

            //if (x > 250) {
                Bitmap reDrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
                dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
            /*} else {
                Bitmap reDrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        width, height, matrix, true);
                dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
            }*/
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There r 2 side-effects. 1.]Starting rotation clock-wise from Left hale part OR 2.]Starting rotation anti-clockwise from Right half part. In these both cases, it Rotates image for 1.5 rotations. That is my logic's limitation up to this time. If I will update it, I'll inform u.

Comment: @Maulik, If you try my demo and get any problem, then inform me by commenting here.